# Can't pass html into tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, tinymce

I have saved raw html content into my database
And I will like to load them into my tinymce editor so that users can just edit the content and submit again. Below is the form;

```
 <textarea id="postfullOnEditPop" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter full post here" required>
 </textarea>
```

I tried to pass the content into TinyMCE like this;

```
tinymce.get('postfullOnEditPop').setContent(postfull);
```

but I get raw html tags instead of formatted text in the TinyMCE editor

Please does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
`tinymce.get('postfullOnEditPop').setContent(postfull, {format: 'raw'});`

The [API](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#editor) isn't super helpful here, unfortunately.